# WSO2 EMM Installation Guidance Needed

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have been trying to create a POC using the EMM product ,but unfortunately it has been a nightmare. I have found the instructions on the products website a bit vague. If anyone can assist that would be much appreciated.
Steps so far completed:

downloaded the binary's

1. Using OS: linux
2. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_55
3. export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
4. installed mysql
5. ran the DB script on the DB source /dbscripts/emm_mysql.sql;
6. configured the mysql Datasource

now that application has issues with the datasources :

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

Does anyone have a working POC that I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

seems you missed the general server configuration on installation. follow this..

https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM101/General+Server+Configurations

Comment: Yes, I know there was an issue with the datasources and have since resolved them.  The website for the product does not stay on point with the same OS for configuration. Would you happen to know if you could load the this product directly onto a mobile device without having to email the user a link to download the app?? Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Also would you know where I could get better clarification on why/how to configure steps  10 and 12?

Answer (score 0):

You need configure the masterdatasources.xml which is step 9 in [EMM documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM101/General+Server+Configurations). Follow the General server configuration. You need to follow the steps to configure Android or iOS client depending on which device(s) you want to check.